# $ty''+4y'=0$ , how to solve it by reduction?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'am struggling with this equation. I need to use reduction method, where $u=y(t)$ and $y''(t)=u'u$. What I get is: $u'tu+2u=0$, then I divide it by $tu$ and get $u'+\frac{2}{t}=0$ (of course assumed $ut$ is not $0$). But what now? Integrate it? In respect to what? What type of equation is it?

Comment: what is reduction method? its variable separable

Comment: Sądząc po nicku, nazwa "równanie o zmiennych rozdzielonych" będzie zrozumiała. (Do you understand Polish?)

Comment: Tak tak :) Dobrze Pan wnioskuje ;) Dziękuję, tak też myślałem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ty''+4y'=0$$

Let $$y'=u$$

$$y'' =u'$$

$$tu'+4u=0$$
$$u'=-(4/t) u$$

$$u=ct^{-4}$$
$$y'=ct^{-4}$$
$$y=c_1t^{-3}+c_2$$

Comment: $$u'=-4u/t \text{?}$$

Comment: The solution given in book is: $y(t) = \frac{C}{t} + D$

Comment: @Rócherz Thanks for correction. I edited my answer.

Comment: @moorzyn The solution given in book does not work.  Typo?

Comment: Yes, typo here. $y(t)=\frac{C}{t^3}+D$ is the correct one :) Thank you very much!